# Error in react build - Property 'key' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, tsx

when I want to build my react project, I face to this error:

`Property 'key' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps'. key={key}`

And also I have error in my .tsx file. like below

[image]

And the wonder is I haven't this error last week.

this project is wrote by TS and config with vite.

Do you have any idea?